# Terminal command to show FileVault and Firewall settings

Tags: terminal, command-line

I'm as a system admin and a big pain is physically checking people's private MacBooks for FileVault and firewall settings.

Is there a way to get the Terminal to output the FileVault and Firewall settings?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  It looks like you got both answers. In the future, please try to stick with one question per question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the FileVault status with:

```
fdesetup status
```

You get the Application Firewall status with:

```
/usr/libexec/ApplicationFirewall/socketfilterfw --getglobalstate
```

You get a verbose pf status with:

```
sudo pfctl -sa
```

Further readings: `man fdesetup|pfctl` and `/usr/libexec/ApplicationFirewall/socketfilterfw -h`.